# Convert time zone into a double

Tags: c#, timezone

I would like to know how I can convert the timezone you get from
`TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset.TotalHours.ToString()` (in this case, the code entered would display a number -7, my timezone). The problem is that if I enclose that line of code with a `Convert.ToDouble()` method, it gives an error because of the negative symbol. It wouldn't be a problem if the timezone I was in didn't have a negative symbol to it. Is there a way to get just the number and not the negative symbol? (I can figure out negative timzones later...)

Comment: Is there any reason you're calling `ToString` in the first place? `TotalHours` itself returns a double, so you can just store that in a variable instead of parsing it with `Convert.ToDouble()`

Comment: Karl's answer is what you asked for, but please make sure you are not just storing this number as "the time zone".  A time zone cannot be represented by just a single number.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  You would instead need to use the string from `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the absolute value via the `Math.Abs` method, like this:

```
int value = (int)Math.Abs(TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset.TotalHours);
```

Note: This will make `-7` return `7`.